# Question about Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: integration

Is upper limit x in $G(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ treated as a constant? I am referring to this question [A question about Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579675/a-question-about-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus). If so then $G'=0$ For example $G(x)=\int_a^x\frac{1}{t}dt=\ln{x}-\ln{a}$ then $G'=(\ln{x}-\ln{a})'=0$ since both are constants.

Comment: *A priori*, it is not.

Comment: If $x$ is treated like a constant on one side of an equality, it must be treated like a constant on the other side as well. And writing $G(x)$ and then saying that you treat $x$ as a constant seems strange to me. In that case, $G'$ would automatically be $0$ as well, even without comparing to the other side.

Comment: Not if you are differentiating with respect to $x$.

Comment: It's treated like when $h$ is a function that sends any number $x$ to the number $h(x)$ and $h'$ is the function that sends any number $x$ to the number $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{h(x+t)-h(x)}{t}$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I'm confused :D. So above it is a consant?

Comment: Can you differentiate with respect to a constant?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I'm confused since $\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is a graph under the curve with respect to t

Comment: It is the area under the curve depending on $x$. If you change $x$, your area changes. The question is if you want to treat $x$ as a constant or a variable, Depending on that, your above work will be justified as right or wrong.

Comment: The symbol $\int_{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$ depends only on three things $a, x, f$ (the $t$ is dummy and is specifically used to represent the function $f$ via some formula). Now you have put it as $G(x) $ which means you have already assumed that $a, f$ remain fixed during entire discussion. So the only thing which varies here is $x$.